# IPython fails to import Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conda, geopandas

After successfully installing the [Geopandas](http://geopandas.org/install.html#installing-geopandas) conda package from the conda-forge as follows:

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

When I try to import it in IPython (Jupyter notebook), using:

```
import geopandas as gpd
```

I consistently receive the following error, despite having all the dependencies (numpy, pandas, shapely, fiona, six, pyproj) installed and up-to-date:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-1-13760ce748ee> in <module>()
      4 import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
      5 
----> 6 import geopandas as gpd
      7 import seaborn as sns
      8 from sklearn import preprocessing

    //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
      3 
      4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
      5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/geoseries.py in <module>()
      6 from pandas import Series, DataFrame
      7 from pandas.core.indexing import _NDFrameIndexer
----> 8 from pandas.util.decorators import cache_readonly
      9 import pyproj
      10 from shapely.geometry import box, shape, Polygon, Point

ImportError: No module named decorators
```

Any suggestions on what might be causing the error?

Comment: update pandas to 0.20.1 and this will be fixed

Comment: thank you, updating to 0.20.1 resolved it

Comment: I still have this issue in (0.2.1) - I do not know the numbering convention: is 0.20.1 and 0.2.1 the same?

Answer (score 1):

To make the comment of Jeff stand out more, this was fixed in pandas 0.20.1.
So normally, if you now install the latest pandas version (not 0.20.0), you should not get this error.

Comment: this still happens in 0.2.1, I get the same error: mport geopandas as gpd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\geopandas.py", line 12, in <module>
    from geopandas import GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame
ImportError: cannot import name GeoSeries